# flip all sideways figures

Tags: rotating

I am using sidewaysfigure for many of my figures.

When I print out my document, for reasons I don't understand, the figure captions are on the inside and not the outside.

Is there a quick way to flip all the sideways figures without affecting anything else?

Answer (score 1):

```
\usepackage[counterclockwise]{rotating}
```

rotates the figures anticlockwise.

```
\usepackage[clockwise]{rotating}
```

rotates them clockwise.

```
\usepackage[figuresleft]{rotating}
```

rotates all figures so that the captions are on the left, regardless of whether the page is odd or even.

```
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
```

rotates all figures so that the captions are on the right, regardless of whether the page is odd or even.

Comment: Thank you. This didn't seem to work for me. I tried [clockwise] also, but my figures appear to be in the same orientation. Any idea why?

Comment: @user1551817 Sorry. I think I was confusing the `(counter)clockwise` options with the `figuresleft(right)` ones. See edit. If you would post a minimal example document, I could test an answer. But hopefully one of the `figures` options is what you want.